# Python / rq - How to pass information from the caller to the worker?

Tags: python, flask, redis, plotly-dash, python-rq

I want to use rq to run tasks on a separate worker to gather data from a measuring instrument. The end of the task will be signaled by a user pressing a button on a dash app.
The problem is that the task itself does not know when to terminate since it doesn't have access to the dash app's context.

I already use `meta` to pass information from the worker back to the caller but can I pass information from the caller to the worker?

Example task:

```py
from rq import get_current_job
from time import time

def mock_measurement():
    job = get_current_job()
    t_start = time()

    # Run the measurement
    t = []
    i = []
    job.meta['should_stop'] = False # I want to use this tag to tell the job to stop
    while not job.meta['should_stop']:
        t.append(time() - t_start)
        i.append(np.random.random())
        job.meta['data'] = (t, i)
        job.save_meta()
        sleep(5)
    print("Job Finished")
```

From the console, I can start a job as such

```py
queue = rq.Queue('test-app', connection=Redis('localhost', 6379))
job = queue.enqueue('tasks.mock_measurement')
```

and I would like to be able to do this from the console to signify to the worker it can stop running:

```py
job.meta['should_stop'] = True
job.save_meta()
job.refresh
```

However, while the commands above return without an error, they do not actually update the `meta` dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't fetch the updated meta. **But, don't do this!!**
Invoking save_meta and refresh in caller and worker will lose data.

Instead, Use `job.connection.set(job + ':should_stop', 1, ex=300)` to set flag, and use `job.connection.get(job + ':should_stop')` to check if flag is set.

Comment: Thank you!
Just to clarify if anyone else has the same question, I ended up using `queue.connection.set(job.key + b':should_stop', 1, ex=30)` on the caller side and `connection.get(job.key + b':should_stop')` on the worker side.

Comment: @DougP. you're right,  `self.connection` and `self.key()` should be `job.connectoin` and `job.key`.